# Matching KeyPath in application with Wallet32 Keypath for Bip44 wallets

Tags: wallet, bip32-hd-wallets, c#, mnemonic-seed

I have an application where I create an HD wallet with a passphrase and save the public master key to the database for the user.

Then, I want the user to be able to back up the wallet to their own wallet, in this case I am using Wallet32. I restore the account in Wallet32, which uses a key path of m/44'/0'/0'/

On my application side, I am creating the keypath like so (in c#):

```
KeyPath newKeyPath = new KeyPath("44/0/0/0/0" + nextDerivation);
var childKey = pubkey.Derive(newKeyPath);
```

The nextDerivsation variable just increments with each purchase. When the derived public key is created on the application side, it doesn't match up with a derived public key in wallet32. So, if a payment is made through the application, Wallet32 doesn't pick it up.

I am using the C# NBitcoin library. When I try to add the apostrophes in the keyPath string like so:

```
KeyPath newKeyPath = new KeyPath("44'/0'/0'/0/0" + nextDerivation);
var childKey = pubkey.Derive(newKeyPath);
```

Then I get an "invalid input format" error. I am unsure as to whether those apostrophes are necessary or not, but when I input that same derivation path into the Bip32 generator, then I can create the same public keys. I can send a payment to the derived address and wallet32 picks it up.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on what I need to use for the KeyPath in the NBitcoin library to obtain the same results?

Answer (score 1):

Response on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299204/matching-keypath-in-application-with-wallet32-keypath-for-bip44-wallets/27627358#27627358

Short answer : now the "44'/0'" notation has been implemented, just update your package of NBitcoin.